# How to make user inputed string have the value of a double variable

Tags: java

I am creating an project where when the user inputs a word, the word will have the value of an already existing double variable. How would I make the word be able to equal the double variable when the user types it in? After the user types the word in, the input will be put into another math equation.

```
double answer = 5.5;

System.out.print("1st number: ");
System.out.print("Enter first number: ");

first = scanner.nextDouble();
// user inputs "Previous" , and the value is of the answer variable
            
System.out.print("Enter second number: ");
second = scanner.nextDouble();
// user inputs 1.1

answer = first + second;
//5.5+1.1=6.6
```

Comment: If you call `nextDouble` Scanner will only recognise a number, not a word like "Previous".

Comment: As a hint, you won't be able to use `scanner.nextDouble()` if the expected value might not be a double. You'll need to use `next()` to read it as a `String`, then check to see if the value is "Previous" (or any other string that has significance in your program) or otherwise try to parse it as a double.

Comment: Would that still work if I wont know if the user will enter the phrase or a double. It is all depending on if the user wants to input the word "previous" to make the "first number" the same as the previous answer, or if they wanted a totally new number.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the input as a String and convert it to a double.

`double first = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());`

EDIT:

To handle if the user selects "previous" or inputs a number, you could use a try catch. parseDouble throws an exception if it cannot turn a String into a double. So if Double.parseDouble("previous") would throw an exception, while Double.parseDouble("3.55") would not.

This would look something like:

```
first = scanner.nextLine();
double firstNumber;

try{
    firstNumber = Double.parseDouble(first);
}
catch(NumberFormatException e){
    if(first.equals("previous")){
         firstNumber=answer;
}
```

Comment: Would that still work if I wont know if the user will enter the phrase or a double. It is all depending on if the user wants to input the word "previous" to make the "first number" the same as the previous answer, or if they wanted a totally new number.

Comment: Now that I understand your question better, I edited my response. You can use a try catch.

Comment: Personally, I would check for the known string _before_ trying to parse it, to avoid having to handle that case in the `catch` block. It’s really a matter of preference, however.